# Get <a> Title and Print as caption using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, debugging

I have the following function to take the title of `a.preview` and append it inside of `p#preview`, some AJAX content which is generated on hover.  This is a small piece of what's happening overall, but the variable `c` in the following script should be the title of `a.preview`.  For some reason, I'm getting a null response.  The title is printing elsewhere so I know that's not the problem, it's either in the variable definition or in the calling of the variable.  Any debug suggestions?

```
$("a.preview").hover(function(e){
    this.t = this.title;
    this.title = "";    
    var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
    $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ this.href +"' alt='Image preview ... Loading' />"+ c +"</p>");
    $("#preview")
            .hide()
        .css("top",(e.pageY - yOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + xOffset) + "px")
        .fadeIn("2000");                        
},
```

Comment: Why not just do `var t` instead of `this.t`? Are you meaning to set a new attribute?

Comment: `this.t` is because the content is AJAX and there are many instances each with their own unique title that needs to be printed differently.

Comment: And just in case you were right I just tried it and it returns `undefined` when I change `this.t` to `var t` :/

Comment: Weird, it is working for me...have you checked your `<a>` to make sure the title is there and not malformed?

Comment: Yeah, I have, the title is fine :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this on Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jsNcn/

Looks fine to me?

Comment: Hmm... no, my fault. Your example is working.  Now if I could figure out why mine isn't :/

Comment: Maybe you need to show us some more code. You are aware about the comma in the end? Should be replaced with ); - like in my example.

Comment: Ok, here's a JSfiddle that includes ALL of my working code: http://jsfiddle.net/jsNcn/3/

Comment: I would do some refactoring, maybe build it like jQuery widget. See my example: http://jsfiddle.net/jsNcn/4/ - don't know if that is the best idea, but my guess is that it could help you're overview.

Comment: Thanks @designer!  I did end up going a different direction however your answer is the most relevant to the original question. Thank you so much for your help!